# Why would you commit a transaction within a catch clause?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Microsoft has the following example for try...catch in tsql:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO

-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will render the transaction uncommittable
-- when the constraint violation occurs.
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- A FOREIGN KEY constraint exists on this table. This 
        -- statement will generate a constraint violation error.
        DELETE FROM Production.Product
            WHERE ProductID = 980;

    -- If the delete operation succeeds, commit the transaction. The CATCH
    -- block will not execute.
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Test XACT_STATE for 0, 1, or -1.
    -- If 1, the transaction is committable.
    -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should 
    --     be rolled back.
    -- XACT_STATE = 0 means there is no transaction and
    --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.

    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +
              ' Rolling back transaction.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    -- Test whether the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is committable.' + 
              ' Committing transaction.'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
    END;
END CATCH;
GO
```

Source for above sample: [Using TRY...CATCH in Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx)

I don't understand why you'd want to commit a transaction that resulted in an exception.  It seems like at least 9 times out of 10 you'd want to IF (XACT_STATE()) !=0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION.  Why would you want a partial success over a clean slate?

Comment: I tried to trim some of the comments to make the sample sql shorter... but SO throws an exception when I try to edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

This sample is completely wrong. Is understandable to have a try-catch block to deal with a key duplicate and recover and do an alternate operation (perhaps an update instead of the insert). But to have a block of code the COMMITS in case of success, but **leaves the transaction open** in case of error, and, even more, **silently swallows the error** is just mind blowing. This piece of code is a big big can of worms.

On my site there is a sample [procedure template that handles errors and transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) correctly, allowing for embedded transaction to recover and continue on error **correctly**. Typical examples where you'd want the handling to recover on case of error is batch processing: as you progress through the batch, you savepoint before each record then attempt to process. If processing fails, you save the record in a failed table and continue *without loosing the whole batch*.

**Update**

LOL, I missed the commit in the catch too. Then is not that bad as my original comment. I still prefer my template, that uses a savepoint and allows for nested transactions.